# No county outlines in ggplot counties plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm using R-3.2.2 and the latest version of Rstudio as of 10/5/2015

```
library("ggplot2")
library("maps")

counties <- map_data("county")

qplot(long, lat, data = counties, geom = "polygon", group = group, fill = group)
```

When I view in the RStudio plot window, I cannot see the white outlines of the counties.
When I save the plot as a PDF I *can* see (very faintly) the county outlines.

When I run the same lines of code on my MacBook (as opposed to my PC above), county lines show up perfectly.

Any idea what I cannot see county outlines?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `col` argument to your plot:

```
qplot(long, lat, data = counties, geom = "polygon", group = group, 
      fill = group, col = I('white'))
```

[image]